# Selectively combining two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to selectively combine the data from two dataframes. DF1 contains team statistics (e.g., points, rebounds, assists) averaged by three different teams (e.g., A, B, C) per year. DF2 shows the outcomes when these teams play on another.

DF1:

| Year | Team | PTS | REB | AST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | A | 100 | 50 | 30 |
| 2015 | B | 110 | 56 | 29 |
| 2015 | C | 116 | 53 | 31 |
| 2016 | A | 100 | 54 | 35 |
| 2016 | B | 112 | 57 | 28 |
| 2016 | C | 110 | 46 | 34 |
| 2017 | A | 115 | 50 | 21 |
| 2017 | B | 120 | 49 | 25 |
| 2017 | C | 105 | 51 | 27 |

DF2:

| Year | Team 1 | Team 2 | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | A | B | A |
| 2015 | B | C | B |
| 2016 | A | C | C |
| 2016 | B | A | A |
| 2017 | C | B | C |
| 2017 | A | B | A |

I would like to combine these dataframes so that the annual statistics of each team are added alongside their respective teams, as shown in DF3.

DF3:

| Year | Team 1 | Team 1 PTS | Team 1 REB | Team 1 AST | Team 2 | Team 2 PTS | Team 2 REB | Team 2 AST | Winner |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | A | 100 | 50 | 30 | B | 110 | 56 | 29 | A |
| 2015 | B | 110 | 56 | 29 | C | 116 | 53 | 31 | B |
| 2016 | A | 100 | 54 | 35 | C | 110 | 46 | 34 | C |
| 2016 | B | 112 | 57 | 28 | A | 100 | 54 | 35 | A |
| 2017 | C | 105 | 51 | 27 | B | 120 | 49 | 25 | C |
| 2017 | A | 115 | 50 | 21 | B | 120 | 49 | 25 | A |

I have tried to use DataFrame.merge() along with moving and dropping some columns, and it works, but the merged dataframe is missing over half of the expected rows.

```
DF3 = DF2.merge(DF1, left_on=['Year','Team 1'], right_on=['Year','Team'])
DF3 = DF3.merge(DF1, left_on=['Year','Team 2'], right_on=['Year','Team'])
```

I am curious if anyone has any better solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehension for join by columns from list `cols` by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html), rename new columns with [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last join together with last column `Winner` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
cols = ['Team 1', 'Team 2']

dfs = [DF2[['Year', x]].join(DF1.set_index(['Year','Team'])
                       .add_prefix(f'{x} '), on=['Year', x]) for x in cols]


df = pd.concat(dfs + [DF2[['Winner']]], axis=1)

print (df)
   Year Team 1  Team 1 PTS  Team 1 REB  Team 1 AST  Year Team 2  Team 2 PTS  \
0  2015      A         100          50          30  2015      B         110   
1  2015      B         110          56          29  2015      C         116   
2  2016      A         100          54          35  2016      C         110   
3  2016      B         112          57          28  2016      A         100   
4  2017      C         105          51          27  2017      B         120   
5  2017      A         115          50          21  2017      B         120   

   Team 2 REB  Team 2 AST Winner  
0          56          29      A  
1          53          31      B  
2          46          34      C  
3          54          35      A  
4          49          25      C  
5          49          25      A
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong - it looks fine. But what is the difference in output to the double merge approach?

Comment: @P.Jo - Testing OP solution, there is problem appended new repeated columns and problematic rename `PTS,REB,AST` columns